# undefined variable and undefined index

Tags: php

**steps.php**

```
<?php        
    function allowed_in($steps){        
    $steps = array('Text1.php', 'Text2.php', 'Text3.php');                
    $latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];            
    }        
?>
```

**Text1.php:**

```
<?php
   if(allowed_in($steps)){      
      //all code in the create_session.php             
   }
?>
```

I am trying to store a php variable to a session vairable and access a function in another page but I am getting the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: steps in ... on line 28
>   Notice: Undefined index: latestStep in ... on line 49

I just need to ask how to fix these errors. Do I need an `if(isset())` for the `$_SESSION` variable?

**UPDATE:**

Below is full code:

```
    <?php

    function allowed_in($steps){

    $steps = array('create_session.php', 'QandATable.php', 'individualmarks.php', 'penalty.php', 'penaltymarks', 'complete.php');

    // Track $latestStep in either a session variable
    // $currentStep will be dependent upon the page you're on

    if(isset($_SESSION['latestStep'])){
   $latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
}
else{
   $latestStep = "";
}
    $currentStep = basename(__FILE__); 

    $currentIdx = array_search($currentStep, $steps);
    $latestIdx = array_search($latestStep, $steps);

    if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx > 1 ) {

       return 1;

    } else {

        return 0;

    }

    }

    ?>

    create_session.php:
    if(allowed_in($steps)){

    //all code in the create_session.php

    }else{
    ?>

    <div class="boxed">
      <a href="<?= $pages[$currentPages+1] ?>">Continue</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="create_session.php" id="createLink">Create New</a>
    </div>

    <?php   

    }

    ?>
```

The pseudo code I am trying to follow:

```
function allowed_in($pased_vars){

//your code

if($foo){
    return 1;
}else{
    return 0;
}

}

on included pages
<?php
//include file with code

if(allowed_in($vars)){
//allowed
}else{
//not
}
```

Comment: The first means `$steps` is being used before doing `$steps = ...` somewhere. The second is the same for an array index.

Comment: `$latestStep = isset($_SESSION['latestStep']) ? $_SESSION['latestStep'] : null;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an undefined variable used as `$steps` and an undefined array index used as `$_SESSION['latestStep']`.

Also this:

```
function allowed_in($steps) {
    $steps = array('Text1.php', 'Text2.php', 'Text3.php');
```

doesn't make any sense.
You expect a variable `$steps` passed as parameter to the function and you immediately replace his value inside the function scope? Why would you do that? Just don't expect any parameter to the function and define `$steps` inside it.

To fix the index problem you can use `isset()` and deal with the case the session variable is not set:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['latestStep'])) { /* what if not set? */ }
```

and remember to always use `session_start()` before trying to access `$_SESSION` variables.

For the undefined variable error:

```
<?php
   if(allowed_in($steps)){      
      //all code in the create_session.php             
   }
?>
```

means that `$steps` is not defined. I don't see anywhere that you define `$steps = ...` before passing it as a parameter to the `allowed_in` function. That's the problem.

I'd suggest you to simply define `allowed_in` as `function allowed_in()` and call the above code as:

```
if (allowed_in()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please look at my update to make sure if I should do what you stated for second part in fixing the undefined variable error?

Comment: @user1830984, yes you should.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Check these:-

1) First you didn't return anything to the page. Then how can you check if condition?

2) Have you included the page in another page?

3) Check where have you defined the session variable $_SESSION['latestStep']

4) Check whether you started the session session_start().

5) you are defining the $steps array in steps.php. Then what are you passing to the function allowed_in from text1.php..

Comment: The word is 'you', not 'u'. Please use proper English here and not txt spk.

Comment: @vascowhite Sorry.. Shorthand writing practice. Wont'be repeated in future posts.

Comment: If you edit them out. I'll remove my down vote.

Comment: Well a bit. I did the rest for you.

Comment: @vascowhite  Thanks. i will take care my future posts

Comment: @EdwinAlex To be honest I don't know what is suppose to be in the `function $allowed_in()`, I just guessed its was `$steps` but don't know what it should be

Comment: Can you please look at my update to make sure if I should do what you stated for second part in fixing the undefined variable error?

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset`

You can do like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['latestStep'])){
   $latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
}
else{
   $latestStep = "";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php